# Center text under horizontally aligned buttons

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have these link buttons with text underneath. Right now I am using a table to get everything into alignment. But my boss wants wants a mouseover to trigger both the image and the text state to change. So ideally I would wrap both image and text in `<a>` and use css:hover. But I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried lists so far with no success. I would like something like:

```
<li><img src="" /><br /><a>href</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ?

- make the buttons floated so they can have widths
- set their width
- put both image and text inside the link
- do `text-align:center`

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kGd8c/

Comment: I knew it would be something simple, but couldn't figure it out. Thanks for the fiddle. Awesome example.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't wotk simply set `text-align:center` on the `li` ?

Comment: Close, but when I add in the breaks it caused the next icon to drop down a line. The trick was center + float.